# Using a field value as an argument for another field's combo box

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2013

I have an field with a name of `merchandise_id`. I'd like to use this value in the field for the SQL for another field called `orientations` which shows a combo box.

This is my sql for the row source for the combo box field, but shows all the orientations, not just those for the merchandise_id

```
SELECT orientations.id, orientations.title 
  FROM orientations 
  WHERE [orientations].[merchandise_id]=[merchandise_id]
```

How can I use the field value in this sql query?

Comment: At this moment, no form, just using the datasheet view of the table

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to have a parameter input from the sounds of it. Declare a parameter input then match the form input to the parameter in SQL. In SQL you will see it look something like this:

```sql
PARAMETERS merchandiseID INT
SELECT orientations.id, orientations.title 
FROM orientations 
WHERE [orientations].[merchandise_id]=[merchandiseID];
```